# Magento – Display New Products on Homepage

Tags: magento-1.9

i am using this code

```
{{block type="catalog/product_new" column_count="6" products_count="12" name="home.catalog.product.new" alias="product_homepage" template="catalog/product/new.phtml"}}
```

but did not show on front end.

Comment: You have products that are in stock, with quantity and assigned to a category and store view? If so, check that your template exists.

Answer (score 1):

Try marking the products you want to appear with New date. You can do this from the backend, select the product you want and on the general setting scroll down and select the start date and if you want the end date.